# Is there a way to embed ppt in angular and view through office?

Tags: angular

I am trying to open a ppt in angular using the following code

```
<iframe
  src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src={urlencode(url)}'
  width='962px' height='565px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

but I am getting an error page
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VZGO.png)

Comment: I have even used ngx-doc-viewer but the result is the same. I am able to do this with gview but I have to do this using office

Answer (score 2):

For solving this you need to use DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl :-

you need to bind the source of your iframe with variable of type SafeResourceUrl defined in typescript file.

and then using the instance of sanitizer you need to bypasssecuritytrusturl.

```
url:SafeResourceUrl;
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
  const baseUrl = 'https://example.com';
  this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(baseUrl);
}
```

Comment: @AManoj Have u tried opening this specific url in the browser tab? If you haven't then u should try that check whether it is opening or not. If it's still not opening then most probably its an issue related to the url that u are trying to open.